# Cannot perform INSERT INTO using DateTime to save timestamp in MS Access

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net

I am trying to save a username and a DateTime object to an MS-Access database but I get a "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."  When I debug the program I see that the date is being properly passed.  Also, I completely removed the DateTime information and used the insert command with just the username and it save correctly, so it has something to do with the DateTime itself but I don't know what.  Here is the associated code:

```
//event handler for Begin Program button
private void btnBeginProgram_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //assign DateTime object to current computer date/time 
  busObject.DtDate = DateTime.Now;

  //assign input to busObject.UserName property
  busObject.UserName = txtEnterName.Text;   

  //call method to save input data
  busObject.SaveData();           

  this.Close();
}

//properties for variables and objects
public string UserName
{
  get { return userName; }
  set { userName = value; }
}

public DateTime DtDate
{
  get { return dtDate; }
  set { dtDate = value; }
} 

//method to call SaveData method in ProgramLoginDAL class
public void SaveData()
{
  ProgramLoginDAL.SaveData(this);
}

//method to save user input to database
public static void SaveData(ProgramLoginBOL busObject)
{
  try
  {
    OleDbCommand cmd = aConnection.CreateCommand();

    String sSQLCommand = "INSERT INTO ProgramLogin (UserName, DateTime) VALUES (?,?)";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", busObject.UserName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", busObject.DtDate);

    if (aConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
      aConnection.Open();
    }

    cmd.CommandText = sSQLCommand;
    // Execute the SQL command
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    aConnection.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");                
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show("Error! Data was not saved.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try placing brackets around your field name.  It's probably a keyword:

```
String sSQLCommand = "INSERT INTO ProgramLogin (UserName, [DateTime]) VALUES (?,?)";
```

For DateTime, you might have to specify the data type:

```
sSQLCommand .Parameters.Add(
  new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.Date) { Value = busObject.DtDate });
```

Comment: Doing that gives me a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."  I'll try using something other than DateTime and see if that helps.

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie Updated answer.  Looks like you have to specify the DataType when using DateTime variables.

Comment: @ LarsTech: That did it!  Thank you very much!  I just learned about inserting using parameters today from an earlier post and I would have never figured this out.  U da Man! (or woman as the case may be) :)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the command text before setting the parameters... This may be nothing, but I've never seen it done in that order...

Comment: OK, I did that but it didn't help.  Thanks for the info in the order though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try giving different names to the parameters?

```
String sSQLCommand = "INSERT INTO ProgramLogin (UserName, DateTime) VALUES (@Name,@Date)";           

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", busObject.UserName);     
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", busObject.DtDate);
```

Comment: @ Fiona Holder: Tried that but get "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error"  I also replaced DateTime with DtDate.

Comment: Are you sure that the DateTime column in your ProgramLogin table in the database is set up to be of type datetime?

Comment: Yes I triple checked it.  Thanks to LarsTech we got it figured out.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ProgramLogin (UserName, [DateTime]) values (@userName, @date)";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", busObject.UserName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", busObject.DtDate);
```

Comment: @ Leniel Macaferi: I tried the above code and receive a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error.  I then went ahead and changed DateTime in MS Access to DtDate in case DateTime was causing problems but receive the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Although the OleDb provider use positional parameters instead of named parameters is not a good thing to have two parameter with the same name inside the collection.

Also, if you are using an access database the DateTime is a reserved word. Need to be encapsulated in square brackets

Comment: I tried all of that and now receive a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error.